# How to return a data path using class in python

Tags: python, function, class, object, glob

I want to read in multiple files into python using a glob package and class in python. I want my function to take two parameters. Namely, a path and a parameter that the function that returns.

Here is my attempt.

```
import glob as g
converterPath = r"C:\Users\MyfilePath"

class collect_datafiles:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        try:
            self.a = a
            self.b = g.glob(a)
        except:
            print("Error - While collecting InputFiles")
    def file_list(self):
        return self.b

collect_datafiles(converterPath,0)
```

Where `a` is an argument that holds a path of the data files and `b` is an argument that I want the function to return.

But the above code doesn't seem to work and throwing `TypeError: collect_datafiles() takes no arguments`. Can anyone help me with how to solve this problem?

Comment: your `__init__` method is spelled `__inti__` so it will not take any arguments upon initialization. I don't think you should use a `class` for this unless it is a `class DataFileManager`

Comment: I don't "b" is used anywhere in your class and isn't needed. self.b exists even without b.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue if you're confusing a class for a function. If you want to keep your collect_datafiles as a class, you can set the variables `a` and `b` using

`file_holder = collect_datafiles()
file_holder.a = converterPath`